# Error "failed to import bridging header" multiple times

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, bridging-header

I know this seems to be a duplicate, but it's not. Believe me, I've already looked into every solution I could find in here but none of them solved my problem, even tho it was exactly the same as the other errors.

When I try to run my project it gives these 2 errors:

```
/Users/Henrique/Desktop/homework/agenda-app/Homework-Bridging-Header.h:2:9: error: 'FSCalendar/FSCalendar.h' file not found
#import <FSCalendar/FSCalendar.h>
    ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/Henrique/Desktop/homework/agenda-app/Homework-Bridging-Header.h'
```

This is how the project looks:

[image: This is how the project looks]

You can see that everything seems to be fine.

Also, the path in Target > Build Settings > Objective-C Bridging Header is exactly as it should be:

[image]

I've spent three hours trying to fix this, but it doesn't work. I've already recreated the header, re-installed the pods, cleaned the project... it just doesn't work.

Here is a more in depth look into the errors:

[image]

Comment: If you are using `use_frameworks!` in pod file you don't need to use a bridging header. You can directly import as `import FSCalendar`

Comment: This fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As @RJE said:**

"If you are using `use_frameworks!` in pod file you don't need to use a bridging header. You can directly `import` as `import FSCalendar`"

That's what I did and it worked. 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Clean?  Click Product in the menu bar and then click Clean. See if that helps resolve the error.  You also may need to add a Swift bridging header file.  See this link. http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/